# Windows Service that runs every week strictly by monday 4am

Tags: c#, windows-services

I have this Service that MUST run on a weekly basis every Monday 4am. Searching through Google I came up with this code:

```
Timer ServiceTimer;
DateTime scheduleTime;

private void ScheduleRun()
{
    int daySet = (Convert.ToInt16(Settings.Default.DayOfWeekRun) - (int)DateTime.Today.DayOfWeek + 7) % 7;
    scheduleTime = DateTime.Today.AddDays(daySet).AddHours(Convert.ToDouble(Settings.Default.TimeOfDayRun));
    if (daySet == 0 && scheduleTime < DateTime.Now)
    {
        scheduleTime = DateTime.Today.AddDays(7).AddHours(Convert.ToDouble(Settings.Default.TimeOfDayRun));
    }
}

public Airt_Service()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    ServiceTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
    ScheduleRun();
}

protected void ServiceTimer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    TimeSpan ts = new TimeSpan(7, 0, 0, 0);
    runProcessCode();
}

protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    ServiceTimer.Interval = scheduleTime.Subtract(DateTime.Now).TotalSeconds * 1000;
    ServiceTimer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(ServiceTimer_Elapsed);
    ServiceTimer.Start();
}
```

What seems to be missing here? I already tried debugging it and seems to work (with 2mins interval). Is there something wrong having an interval of 1week (in milliseconds)?

Answer (score 4):

The [Windows Task Scheduler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Task_Scheduler) is perfect for running a task once a week. Ideally you would write a console application that does whatever you want to do and [setup a basic task](http://www.howtogeek.com/123393/how-to-automatically-run-programs-and-set-reminders-with-the-windows-task-scheduler/) to run it on Mondays at 4 AM.

Answer (score -1):

I wouldn't write my own scheduler. 
I'd use [Quartz](http://www.quartz-scheduler.net/).

There are jQuery plugins with which you can use to generate the CRON expression.

You can checkout my repository for working code:
https://github.com/ststeiger/CronSharp

Comment: I would not use quartz for something like this. I would use the scheduler that is ALREADY IN THE OPERATING SYSTEM.

Comment: @TomTom: Oh yea, Windows Scheduler, which operates on 15 minute time and requires that 90% of that 15 minutes to be idle in order to determine the computer is actually idle. The scheduler where you cannot schedule hourly tasks with ease/work properly.

Comment: Do not be so ignorant. You can actually schedule accurate enough to THEN wait in a batch script or the program for the exact time. Takes a little thinking. Please try it. It is a LOT better than keeping a program alife for the whole week for it to work once a week. Besides I have never seen the behavior you mention.